# How to Running ADB Shell Command in Android?

Tags: android, shell, adb

I tried to adb command but device not found exception occurred
So, I have tried as follows :

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("adb", "devices");
```

And check the "List of devices attached"

**Q**. Is there any way to run adb shell command in the Android?

Comment: `Activity myActivity = ...` are you trying to run adb on Android ? AFAIK adb is only for SDK on Win,Lin, etc.

Comment: @PeterMmm Ugh, I've tried on Android. there is no ways to run on Android?? :_(

Comment: ADB is for connecting to a *remote* android device.  Unless you are trying to contact yourself via TCP loopback, there's no reason to use it rather than just issue the shell command you want.

Comment: @Chris Stratton / Thanks for your advice. I was trying to turnning on airplane_mode via adb in android(4.2+). / I'll look for the TCP Loopback. Thank you again :D

Comment: I expect you will find that difficult.

Comment: @ChrisStratton / Yep, I gave up :).....